# Как обратится к list внутри JSON через HTML

Tags: html, handlebars

Для передачи данных использую `handlebars`, имеется обект типа :

```
  course : [{
    'name': name,
    'descr': descr,
    lections: [{
          'name':name,
          'descr':descr
       },{ 
          'name':name,
          'descr':descr
       }]
    }]
```

В `HTML` для получения использую `{{}}`, `{{name}}`, `{{descr}}`. Эти поля отображаются.
Как получить информацию с обекта lections ?

Comment: В первый раз слышу что такое handlebars, но ответ гуглится легко https://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: MaximLensky, Да, но lections не один. Нужно что то вроде lections[i] или lections(i)

Comment: Вы не мешайте всё в кучу. Это json или всё же объект в шаблонизаторе? Если второе - то оперируйте тем функционалом, что он и предоставляет.  А для этого смотрите доку